# Launch VBS script from Run box without specifying ".vbs" extension

Tags: windows, path, vbscript, cmd.exe

I would like to launch a VBS script from the Run box without specifying its file extension.

One of these scripts is called "home", located at `C:\Program Files\lin2nt\home.vbs`

In `cmd`, I can simply type `home`, and the above script is called. However, when I type `home` into the Run box, I get the error

> Windows cannot find 'home'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

If I type `home.vbs` into the Run box, it works as desired. How can I make it work without specifying the file extension?

Here are some relevant environment settings:

```
$ echo %Path%
...;C:\Program Files\lin2nt\

$ echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

$ assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBScript.File

$ ftype VBScript.File
VBScript.File="C:\Windows\system32\wscript.exe" //E:vbs //nologo "%1" %%*
```

I have also edited the registry as suggested [here](http://commandwindows.com/runline.htm).

[image: Registry entry]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by switching to C# and generating an EXE.